# H12 errors triggering a downward spiral of escalating memory on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I've been debugging this for weeks with little success so I'd like to know if anybody had more luck which might help others with the same problem tremendously in the future.

Our setup:

- Ruby 2.3.7
- Rails 4.0.12
- Puma 3.11.4
- rack-timeout 0.4.2
- Heroku 2X dynos

Every now and then, one of the dynos gets hit by a wave of H12 errors ([noisy neighbor?](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/797#issuecomment-159606749)). When that happens, the memory escalates gradually making the dyno unusable until it's restarted.

[image]

The memory keeps escalating even after the H12 errors subside:

[image]

Our `rack-timeout` is set to time out requests after 30 seconds. This [might  be](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout/blob/master/doc/risks.md#timing-out-is-inherently-unsafe) the cause/contributing factor though I wasn't able to prove it decisively. Timeouts during IO blocks are also a [possibility](https://github.com/heroku/rack-timeout/blob/master/doc/risks.md#timing-out-during-io-blocks).

I'm happy to provide more info from NewRelic or Papertrail if you guys have seen this before and know what to look for. Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: I have faced the same problem, my third-party services are required to take more than 30 secs but Heroku does not allow more than 30 secs time-out. So if your services required more than 30 secs better to use [long pulling or background services](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout#long-polling-and-streaming-responses)

Comment: Shameless plug, but this might mitigate some of stress on the Dyno: consider using the [`iodine` server](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) for Ruby MRI. From the command line (Procfile) use the `-www public` argument to add static file support (releasing stress from the Ruby app) and set the `-w` (workers) and `-t` (threads) to match your needs. It's written in C, moving some functionality outside the Ruby GIL, such as the static file service. This should improve server-side performance... though I think the memory "leak" you're experiencing might be in the app.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing H12 errors is an indication that Heroku is timing out the request *before* rack-timeout times out the request. You need to reduce your rack-timeout setting to something less than 30 seconds since [that is Heroku's timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). I'd recommend something like 25 seconds.

With that change in place, you should start seeing Rack::Timeout exceptions instead of H12 errors, and you can begin to diagnose the root cause of the timeouts by looking at the stack trace in an exception tracker.

I wouldn't bother investigating the memory issue until you identify the cause of the timeouts. My bet is once you know why your requests are timing out and you resolve that, your memory issue will be resolved as well.

Comment: Thank you, Adam. Good idea, will try that first.